# Array from a print array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

New in php i have a script that print me an array. 
The result look like :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [timestamp] => 1390242176 
                       [length] => 32 
                       [devtoken] => 21440e995d08db7c8a561afeabcb6c4fed4b37d0e1d695065d8143ebc7a4da7b ) 
        [1] => Array ( [timestamp] => 1390241961 
                       [length] => 32 
                       [devtoken] => 29da231c1476beefbb947a48b8d63d5aab3daaf246e431cdf55d191aa0d732b8 ) 
       [2] => Array ( [timestamp] => 1390242596 
                      [length] => 32 
                      [devtoken] => 33f9140027b0387c40debc6bf39dd407846c6be98fb232905c6a1cf920cfc644 ) 
       [3] => Array ( [timestamp] => 1390242333 
                      [length] => 32 
                      [devtoken] => 734d0e413f59f84b37452e98627263abd5db714d1c11fa59997c6ff1ded487c9 ) 
       [4] => Array ( [timestamp] => 1390241668 
                      [length] => 32 
                      [devtoken] => 89f7ffcbc46e6e0b9fb84e5d79b6b7d9e9895706dd70e4dd4774d5a5399b81b2 ) 
       [5] => Array ( [timestamp] => 1390242685 
                      [length] => 32 
                      [devtoken] => 91eb6fb37d94af40eee5dfeb99933cd546d1bc9ee32d4ca048286ccc33ec2f4c ) 
       [6] => Array ( [timestamp] => 1390242799 
                      [length] => 32 
                      [devtoken] => a5b04a2d04cdda4ceca1229d2fcf59c839326badc4f63f64e63d7940df72d447 ) 
       [7] => Array ( [timestamp] => 1390241504 
                      [length] => 32 
                      [devtoken] => af0e938a785276459fcf9691b96aff2f63526d49ec959bf25c9de9d0d8d78c2a ) 
     )
```

I did not write this array to file. 
What i want to do is to paste this in my php file and make a simple array from this text. 
How can i do that ? 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://github.com/hakre/print_r-converter

Comment: `print_r` / `var_dump` are debugging tools - this format isn't designed to be easily parsed back into workable code (and in-fact can't be with more complex structures) - you should serialise your data properly if you wish to reuse it.

Comment: Yep but it is too late, thank for the advice but know i can't go back in time.

Comment: Amal this give me an array which count is 1 ... 
thanks

Comment: @user3237416: [Beautify the `print_r()` output first](http://phillihp.com/toolz/php-array-beautifier/). Then [convert it](http://phpoverflow.eu01.aws.af.cm/print_r/). You'll get the following output: http://pastie.org/8668789

Comment: Tahnk you very much man !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [serialize](http://php.net/serialize) function to output your data.
You can than use that output and put it in the [unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize) function:

```
$myArray = array (
    'key' => 'value',
    'key2' => 'value2'
);

$serialized = serialize($myArray);

echo $serialized;
```

Comment: too complicated for a noob like me but thanks i'll give a try.